# Bootstrap datepicker not woking in modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-datepicker

When I use a datepicker inside a modal the datepicker is not working.

I use the event show.bs.modal to modify some content of the modal on show:

```
$(function(){
    $('#statusModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
        var title = button.data('title');
        var input_date = button.data('date');
        var modal = $(this);

        modal.find('.modal-title').text('Clicked: ' + title);
        modal.find('.modal-body #inputDate').val(input_date);

        $('#inputDate').datepicker();

    }).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (event) {
        $('#inputDate').datepicker('remove');
    });

    $('#inputDate2').datepicker();

})
```

But this event gets fired again when the datepicker opens.
Because of this, it delets the value of the date input. And selecting a date does also not work.

Here a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/f9de9z8x/26/

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: I ended up here after all these years, and replacing show with shown was not an option to me. I fixed the issue with a hack, and proposed a solution that perhaps you could use: https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker/issues/2571

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the `shown` event instead of the `show` event.

```
$('#statusModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kp0q9s9L/

Comment: No prob, though you will notice that you get a "Flash" of the date within the modal, because the JavaScript isn't executed until the modal is visible to the user.

Comment: please, take a look at the comment I have just posted to the question. Perhaps it could help you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

$("input.date-picker").click(function(){

```
$("#ui-datepicker-div").css("z-index",5000);
```

});