# bootstrap datepicker in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-datepicker

I have a modal window in the `#editorWin` div, which can be opened from multiple locations on the page. Each time it has a different content, coming from an Ajax query in the following way:

```
$('#editorWin').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
         $('#modalCont').html('Loading...')
         $.ajax({
                // load AJAX content and overwrite Load... message
         })
});
```

When the modal window is opened, I want to use a Bootstrap Datepicker widget in it. When I click on the datepicker however, the AJAX loaded content of my modal window disappears.

I suspect that opening the datepicker might trigger the `show.bs.modal` event and that messes with my former function but I'm not sure.

There is no JS error in the console.

Comment: I ended up here after all these years, and replacing show with shown was not an option to me. I fixed the issue with a hack, and proposed a solution that perhaps you could use: https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker/issues/2571

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in a similar question: [Bootstrap datepicker not woking in modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28721516/bootstrap-datepicker-not-woking-in-modal?rq=1)

To solve the issue, the `show.bs.modal` had to be replaced by `shown.bs.modal`.